# Is this tennis player a fraudster?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

In this article [Anhörig vann 270.000 kronor – tennisspelare åtalas för mutbrott](https://www.dn.se/sport/anhorig-vann-270-000-kronor-tennisspelare-atalas-for-mutbrott/) it is claimed:

> It seemed that she intentionally hit double errors or lost points on occasions in the match so that she [the player] lost some games. In a long series of matches, the player has consistently lost the second ball in her serve game. At the same time, a close relative [to the player] had been betting heavily on the matches. The police investigation shows that from nine gambling accounts linked to the relative during 2014–2018 on 102 occasions it has been gambled that the tennis player would lose the next point. The games have been played 94 times and the relative has made a profit of just over SEK 270,000. In their report, the gaming companies consider the probability of being able to predict so many point losses to 0.001 per cent, that is, almost non-existent.

The text is a bit unclear exactly what is considered. The cases:

1. Making a double error in your serve game and losing the game
2. your opponent winning his serve game
3. Losing the second ball in your serve game

all should have different probabilities. However, assuming each case had a probability of 50% and the relative had no information about the next point, he would have the probability $p = 50\%$ to guess the outcome correctly. If the guesses are independent, the outcome of a series of guesses of points can be modelled as a Binomial variable with probability mass function
$$
P(k,n,p) = {\displaystyle {\binom {n}{k}}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}}
$$
with $k$ is the number of correct guesses, $n$ is the number of guesses, and $p$ the probability of winning in each point. So the probability of the considered scenario should then be
$$
P(94,102,0.5) \approx 4.3\cdot 10^{-20}
$$
which is extremely unlikely. The probability of guessing 94 correct *or* better should then be the CDF, that is
$$
\sum_{k=94}^{102} P(k,102,0.5)  \approx 4.7\cdot 10^{-20}
$$
which is also unlikely. Both the PDF and CDF values are far away from what is claimed in the text  $p = 0.001\% = 10^{-5}$. So maybe the probability is not 0.5 in each trial. If we plot the function
$$
f(p) = P(94,102,p)
$$
we get
[image]
where the red line is $10^{-5}$. I guess the $p = 0.75$ chance would be reasonable to win your own serve game as a professional player. However, at the maximum of the curve, at $p=0.91$, $f(0.91) = 0.14$, meaning that guessing correctly 94 times out of 102 is 15%, which is not that improbable.

**Q**: I am curious how the gaming companies came up with the number $10^{-5}$, and have I missed anything in my reasoning?

Comment: See https://bleacherreport.com/articles/1020044-mens-tennis-serve-statistics-may-surprise-you